# Partitioning distinguishable objects into indistinguishable blocks

Tags: co.combinatorics

How can you partition n number of distinguishable objects into m number of indistinguishable blocks given that each of the blocks consists of not less than k number of objects.
(k =1 case can be explained by Stirling numbers of second kind and
k= 3 case can be used to obtain number of different ways to partition the set of vertices of a convex n-gon into polygons.)

Comment: You can use graph theory to obtain different ways of partitioning the set of vertices of a convex n-gon into nonintersecting polygons but my issue is important to find number of different ways to partition including intersecting polygons. Is there anyway to do this using trees?

Comment: Let $S$ be a subset of the positive integers. Let $f_S(n,m)$ be the number of partitions of an $n$-element set into $m$ blocks, where the block sizes all belong to $S$. Then $$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\sum_{m\geq 0}f_S(m,n)t^m\frac{x^n}{n!} = \exp t \sum_{k\in S}\frac{x^k}{k!}. $$

Comment: @ Richard Stanley is there no way for explicit function or recursive formula?

Comment: For your question you want the coefficient of $x^n/n!$ in $$ \frac{1}{m!}\left(e^x-1-x-\frac{x^2}{2!}-\cdots-\frac{x^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}\right)^m. $$ You can expand by the multinomial theorem and get a formula that becomes messier as $k$ increases.

Comment: Here you have two special cases,                              1) When m =2 , k=3   number of different ways for n - gon is a(n) = [ 2^n - 2 - 2*n - 2*C ( n,2) ]/2  OEIS A 272352.

Comment: 2) When m =3 , k = 3 number of different ways a(n) is given by the recursive formula,               a(n) = 3*a(n-1)+C(n-1,2)*[  2^(n-4) +2 -n - C(n-3,2)] where n >8 and a(8) =0. OEIS A 272982

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are called "$k$-associated Stirling numbers of the 2nd kind": see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Associated_Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind.

Comment: I checked with my previous research work on partitioning and this is ok with those special cases.

Comment: You can accept this answer if it resolves your question.

Comment: Yes definitely I am totally satisfied with this answer. Since I'm new to this community I didn't know how to show my acceptance.

Comment: There should be some Bell numbers associated also, right? Where each block has at least k members...

Comment: @PerAlexandersson: Sure, I guess so. You can just take a sum of these $k$-associated Stirlings.